# How can I have a fuse-overlayfs filesystem directly show modifictions on the lower layer?

Tags: linux, docker, overlayfs

**Context**

I am exploring some options around overlayfs, in order to mount a directory inside a docker container with a "copy on write" behavior -- the container should be able to read any file from the host directory, but write actions should not reach the original directory.

The current options I am exploring involve creating the overlayfs on the host system before mounting it using `docker run --volume $hostpath:$containerpath ...`.
(if I am missing a way to let docker handle the overlayfs directly, I am interested in being pointed in the right direction).

So right now, I am comparing `sudo mount -t overlay ...` with `fuse-overlayfs ...`.

These actions are intended to be run on a developer's machine, and possibly on our CI systems,
we have no intention on using this to run processes in production.

So running `sudo` actions can be done, however it would be nice if I could figure out a way to run everything as the current user.

**Situation**

From my testing on my Ubuntu 22.10 system (linux 5.19) :

- when I `sudo mount ...` an overlayfs on top of a `lower` directory, if a file in the `lower` directory is modified (and is not "hidden" by some file in the `upper` layer), the updated file is directly visible from the overlay fs
- when I `fuse-overlayfs ...` the same directory, however, it looks like the files presented in the overlay system do not react to changes in the `lower/` directory

Here is a script describing my test:
(fair warning: this script runs `sudo mount` and `sudo umount` actions, please read the code before executing on your machine ...)

```
$ cat test-overlay.sh
#!/bin/bash

# call:
#  - './test-overlay.sh fuse'   for 'fuse-overlayfs' test
#  - './test-overlay.sh'   for 'sudo mount -t overlay' test
#  - './test-overlay.sh umount'  to unmount the filesystem if any mount is left over

set -e


cd $(dirname "$0")

mkdir -p test
cd test

if [[ "$1" == "u" || $1 == "umount" ]]; then
    echo "=== unmounting test/overlay"
    sudo umount overlay
    exit $?
fi

echo "=== setting up test directory:"
echo "    running: 'sudo umount overlay' ..."
sudo umount overlay 2> /dev/null || true

sudo rm -rf overlay upper work lower

mkdir overlay upper work lower

echo "foo - first line" >> lower/foo
echo "bar - first line" >> lower/bar


if [ "$1" = "fuse" ]; then
    echo "=== mounting using fuse-ovelayfs ..."
    fuse-overlayfs -o lowerdir=$PWD/lower,workdir=$PWD/work,upperdir=$PWD/upper $PWD/overlay
else
    echo "=== mounting using sudo mount ..."
    echo "    running: 'sudo mount -t overlay ...'"
    sudo mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=$PWD/lower,workdir=$PWD/work,upperdir=$PWD/upper overlayfs $PWD/overlay
fi

echo "=== expecting 1 line in overlay/foo"

if [ $(wc -l < overlay/foo) -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "  failed: got $(wc -l < overlay/foo) lines instead"
fi

echo "foo: 2nd line" >> lower/foo

echo "=== expecting 2 line in overlay/foo"

if [ $(wc -l < overlay/foo) -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "  failed: got $(wc -l < overlay/foo) lines instead"
fi

# comment next line if you want to keep the filesystem mounted and inspect it:
echo "    running: 'sudo umount overlay' ..." && sudo umount overlay
```

**Question**

Are there some extra options I should set when using `fuse-overlayfs` to have the overlay layer behave as `mount -t overlay` ?

namely :

if a file is not touched or modified in the `upper` layer, directly see the modifications made on the `lower` layer visible from the overlay filesystem